# Edittext field outside scope of alert dialog? Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I created an `AlertDialog` such that when you press a `Button`, the `Dialog` pops up and a `layout` appears with `EditText`s.  However, I created the `layout` in the actual code rather than in the `xml`file.  For some reason, when the `AlertDialog` pops up, it's not able to find the `EditText` field and gives me a `NullPointerException`.

```
//private Lecture lecture;
private LectureManager lectureManager;

public void addWork(View view) {

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    EditText weight = new EditText(this);
    EditText mark = new EditText(this);

    mark.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    weight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    weight.setId(99);
    mark.setId(100);

    layout.addView(mark);
    layout.addView(weight);

    AlertDialog.Builder addwork = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    addwork.setView(layout);

    addwork.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            EditText eweight = (EditText) findViewById(99);
            EditText emark = (EditText) findViewById(100);
            String coursename = ecoursename.getText().toString();
```

And for some reason, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at the "`EditText` weight" line.  I believe that maybe it's not finding anything with ID 99 and that the `EditText` might be out of scope?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: declare edittext as instance variables and get the text in dialog click. no need to set id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you make these calls:

```
EditText eweight = (EditText) findViewById(99);
EditText emark = (EditText) findViewById(100);
```

you're calling the `findViewById()` method of your Activity, not the `AlertDialog`. In order to retrieve the views from the `Dialog`, you can use something like this, inside `onClick()`:

```
EditText eweight = (EditText) ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(99);
EditText emark = (EditText) ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(100);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `final` for both `EditText` while initilization like below

```
final EditText weight = new EditText(this);
final EditText mark = new EditText(this);
```

Then you can get the text from `EditText` in **PositiveButton**

```
String weight_txt = weight.getText().toString().trim();
String mark_txt = mark.getText().toString().trim();
```

No need to set id for `EditText` also no need `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do this

```
EditText eweight = (EditText) view.findViewById(99);
```

and view is , what you have passed in your addWork() method parameter.

Comment: hey, but then it asks me to change view to final

Comment: yes. declare it as final so it will be accessible in the scope.